# Stop listening for 'x' seconds in corona

Tags: events, lua, coronasdk, listen

I have a fade-in/fade-out function based on a shake event, but if you shake it again during the function, it stacks the functions. What I would like is for it to wait until the function ends (5 seconds) and then being listening again. What would the code be for that?

This is what I have currently:

```
function fadeOut ( event )
    transition.to(yes1, {time=2000, alpha=0})
    transition.to(yes2, {time=2000, alpha=0})
    ...
    transition.to(funny3, {time=2000, alpha=0})
    transition.to(funny4, {time=2000, alpha=0})
    timer.performWithDelay(2000, onShakeComplete)
end

responses = {yes1, yes2, yes3, yes4, yes5, yes6, yes7, yes8, yes9, yes10,
no1, no2, no3, no4, no5, maybe1, maybe2, maybe3, maybe4, maybe5,
funny1, funny2, funny3, funny4}

local shaking = false

-- reset shaking flag after a shake is completed
local function onShakeComplete()
    shaking = false
end

local function onShake (event)
        if event.isShake and not shaking then
        shaking = true
        local object = responses[math.random(1,20)]
        transition.to(object, {time=2000, alpha=1})
        timer.performWithDelay(4000, fadeOut)
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("accelerometer", onShake)
```

Comment: You need to show some code to make things a bit more clear what you want. How are you setting up the event handler now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-- true if we have a shake happening right now
local shaking = false

-- reset shaking flag after a shake is completed
local function onShakeComplete()
    shaking = false
end

local function onShake (event)
    if event.isShake and not shaking then
        local object = responses[math.random(1,20)]
        transition.to(object, {time=2000, alpha=1})
        timer.performWithDelay(4000, fadeOut)
        timer.performWithDelay(4000, onShakeComplete)
        shaking = true
    end
end
```

Comment: It's still allowing the functions to be overlapped.

Comment: Then we need more detail. Define "overlapping"? By how much? Does it happen only at the start of a shake event (possible race condition)? Is it a very minor overlap?

Comment: Multiple objects are fading in, but, because of the way I programmed it, they're all fading out at the same time. It's a major overlap, the images can be clearly seen through each other. It only begins to overlap on the initialization of a shake.

Comment: @Mud I suspect that since you turn on the shake event again exactly when fadeOut starts, the fadeOut will overlap with the next fadein.

Comment: @JShoe You should turn it on when the fadeout is complete if you don't want them to overlap at all. A bit hard to tell exactly how without seeing the fadeOut function, but moving the `timer.performWithDelay(4000, onShakeComplete)` to there and changing the 4000 to whatever fadeOut time you have should work.

Comment: I added that code, and updated it in my question. Now there is no overlap, but even after I wait everything out, I cannot call any of the functions again; shaking it after the delay does nothing.

Comment: It's never calling  `onShakeComplete`. That function is local, and declared *below* the point where you use it, so you're passing `nil` to `performWithDelay` inside of `fadeOut`.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry, I figured it out. I put it back where he told me to, and extended the time on it. It works great now. Thanks so much!